# Does anyone have experience of using the Podio API with Joomla or RS Forms?

Tags: joomla, podio

the Podio support team suggested I post a question on this forum as we are looking to connect our forms system (Joomla RS Forms) with Podio.

All of the other forms systems Podio connects with won't really work for us so I am trying to gather information on how complex and expensive this might be.

Any advice would be really appreciated!

Many thanks, Jess

Answer (score 1):

The complexity and cost depends on what you want to do.

It looks like there is a PHP client for the Podio API (see http://podio.github.io/podio-php and https://github.com/podio/podio-php for details.

Joomla is a PHP based CMS so you should be able to use the API to integrate Podio using custom code in RS Forms or ChronoForms or any similar Joomla forms extension.

Comment: Thanks Neil - I'm afraid I'm coming at this without any technical knowledge  but I'll take a look. We basically want to connect a single form so that it will create a new item and populate particular fields within the podio item. Mostly it's text boxes, check boxes and dropdowns, sometimes attached images.